# How could I create an opencv matrix with separate rgb channel data

Tags: opencv, opencv-mat

Suppose I have three char arrays `r[1024], g[1024], b[1024]` which contains the rgb data of one image. How could I create a `cv::Mat` with these channel data ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this:

```
// Create three single channel Mats
cv::Mat R(rows,cols,CV_8UC1,&r[0]);
cv::Mat G(rows,cols,CV_8UC1,&g[0]);
cv::Mat B(rows,cols,CV_8UC1,&b[0]);
```

Then merge into single image:

```
// Now merge the 3 individual channels into 3-band bad boy
auto channels = std::vector<cv::Mat>{B, G, R};
cv::Mat ThreeBandBoy;
cv::merge(channels, ThreeBandBoy);
```